# time does not match format ‘%y-%m-%d’

Tags: python, datetime

I can not match the time using datetime,And try to change the time to '% y /% m /% d' is also useless。
Where is the problem？thank u
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X53My.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNgcm.png)

Has found the problem is that they are inadvertently the details of the proposed low-level issues

Comment: Please support your question with code snippets you've tried out. Make the question clear enough with proper error statements for better understanding

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code should be,

```
date_string = '2014/7/1'
datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d)

>>> date
'2014/7/1'
>>> datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d")
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 0, 0)
>>>
```

The format for string should be `"%Y/%m/%d"`, (capital "Y").

Comment: I modified the capital letters but still error, is it that should modify the file data, 2014/7/1 modified to 2014-7-1 ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the details.

Comment: Could you do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, if you please?

Comment: How can I help you

Comment: You could select my answer and accept it as the right one..!

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) the %m and %d are zero padded and %y is also just the two-digit representation of the year. So the date has to look something like this:

17-07-01

Comment: That is, I need to change the file in 2014/7/1 format 2014-7-1, while modifying the "% Y-% m-% d"?

Comment: Well you either change the format in the data or the date format.